# Angular organization and modularity - controller structure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, structure

I've seen two different approaches to organizing modules and controller structure in Angular 1.x.

The **first**, below, is the way I'm familiar with where you separate out the controllers into their own files and attach them to the parent angular module.

The **second**, create a large controller file to house related controllers and attach them to the parent controller, then inject the controller as a module into the parent angular module.

Which is more performant? Is there a difference?

**App.js**

```
angular
    .module('mainApp', [
        'a bunch of dependencies'
    ])
    .run(['a bunch of dependencies', function(a bunch of dependencies){
```

**myControllerA.js**

```
angular
    .module('mainApp')
    .controller('myControllerA', ['a bunch of dependencies',
        function(a bunch of dependencies) {
```

**myControllerB.js**

```
angular
    .module('mainApp')
    .controller('myControllerB', ['a bunch of dependencies',
        function(a bunch of dependencies) {
```

---

**App.js**

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp', ['mainController', 'a bunch of dependencies']);

app.run(['a bunch of dependencies', function(mainController, a bunch of dependencies) {
```

**mainController.js**

```
var mainController = angular.module('mainController', [
  'a bunch of dependencies'
]);

mainController.config(function(a bunch of dependencies) {
   ...
});

mainController.controller('controllerA', ['a bunch of dependencies', function(a bunch of dependencies) {
  ...

mainController.controller('controllerB', ['a bunch of dependencies', function(a bunch of dependencies) {
  ...
```

Comment: Have a look a this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995605/does-a-large-number-of-modules-hit-performance-of-angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What has been really helpful for me was to follow [this angular styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#single-responsibility).  It is Angular Team endorsed, and due to how things are structured, it makes moving to Angular 2 less painful, if you ever have to do that.

If you don't like that, there is [another style guide](https://github.com/toddmotto/angular-styleguide) that is referenced in the above link that is good as well.

Using either one of these style guides, they both recommend separating out the files.  I don't think this is for performance as much as for ease of use, especially as the application grows.  Having everything in one file will become unsustainable